# Can $2$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ generate a $3$ dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have $2$ vectors: $(1,2,0,1)$ and $(1,3,1,1)$, generating a subspace in R4.

Doing some calculations I get $\{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: w=x \land z=y-2x\}$ (I don't know what this is called in  english, sorry. Bear with me).

So that's: $(x,y,z,w) \land (x,y,y-2x,w)$ which is equivalent to:  $x(1,0,0,1) + y(0,1,0,0) + z(0,0,1,0) \land x(1,0,-2,0) + y(0,1,1,0) + w(0,0,0,1)$

So am I wrong in inferring that this returns $3$ dimensions or did I otherwise do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No. In fact, no $\;n\;$ vectors in **any vector space** can generate a $\;n+1\,-$ dimensional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: w=x , z=y-2x\}&=\{(x,y,y-2x,x) \in \mathbb{R}^4: x, y \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
&=\{x(1,0,-2,1)+y(0,1,1,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}\end{align}

The subspace that you described is $2$ dimensional.

Comment: Ah I see, you're supposed to join the two conditions in one vector. That's where I got it wrong, alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ requires 3 linear independent vectors.